# ForeignKeys not being represented via TastyPie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to get a number of my ForeignKey relationships to show up in my TastyPie output. Here is my model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    safetyreportid = models.SlugField("Safey Report Unique Identifier", max_length=125, primary_key=True)
    safetyreportversion = models.IntegerField("Safety Report Version Number", max_length=125, blank=True, null=True)
    primarysourcecountry = models.CharField("Country of the primary reporter", max_length=3, blank=True)
    occurcountry = models.CharField("Country where the event occured", max_length=3, blank=True)

class Reaction(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    reactionmeddrapt = models.CharField("MedDRA Preferred Term used to characterize the event", max_length=250, blank=True)
    reactionmeddraversionpt = models.CharField("MedDRA version for reaction/event term PT", max_length=100, blank=True)
```

and my API.py file:

```
class ReactionResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Reaction.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'reaction'

class ReportResource(ModelResource):
    reaction = fields.ForeignKey(ReactionResource, attribute='reaction', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Report.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'report'
```

However, even when a relationship (which I can see in the django admin panel) exists, all I get in the JSON output is this:

```
reaction: null,
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example of `safetyreportid` that does not work?

Comment: {
occurcountry: "",
primarysourcecountry: "",
reaction: null,
resource_uri: "/api/report/8480347-2/",
safetyreportid: "8480347-2",
safetyreportversion: null,
},

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship looks reversed.

The `ForeignKey` between the Models does `Reaction` -> `Report`, but in your API, it's `ReportResource` -> `ReactionResource`.

Comment: How else would I associate the report to have multiple reactions inside of it?

Comment: Also, here's what the example in the tutorial on the tastypie docs reads - am I missing something? https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=foreignkey

Comment: @seanherron In Tastypie's example, the `ForeignKey` is  `Entry` -> `User` in  both the Model and the Resource. It's not the case in your code.

Comment: @seanherron It's probably easier to have your API consumers access the reports and filter the reactions. If you really want to include reactions in the reports, you can do use [`ToManyField`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships) - but I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your problem, in case you want to see the reactions inside the report is including a reverse ForeignKey from the `Report` to the `Reaction` resources:

```
class ReportResource(ModelResource):
    reaction_set = fields.ToManyField('yourapp.resources.ReactionResource', 'reaction_set', full=False)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Report.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'report'

class ReactionResource(ModelResource):
    report = fields.ForeignKey(ReportResource, 'report', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Reaction.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'reaction'
```

This ToManyField will show up all the reaction resources URIs to in the `reaction_set` field. The name of the Resource has to be a full string path, given that the Resource has still not been declared. Hope it helps.